# Spring Security – cannot access javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter, spring-security

I'm writing the Spring Boot project with basic authentication and authorization using Spring Security. I have a config class which extends the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (I wanna get rid of it later, since it's deprecated).
So, my config class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("spring_user")
                                     .password("password123")
                                     .roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.codelib</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic-auth-security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>basic-auth-security</name>
    <description>basic-auth-security</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Note that I have `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.

There is nothing interesting in the rest of the project. When I try to run the app, the following message is shown:

```
java: cannot access javax.servlet.Filter
  class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found
```

And IDEA redirects me to the config file. (but no lines of code are underlined with red)

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Your dependencies are wrong. The best way to start a Spring Boot project is to us https://start.spring.io/. It helps to get the right dependencies.

Comment: [Spring Boot 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide): "You need to be especially careful that older Java EE dependencies are no longer directly or transitively used in your build. For example, if you should always be using jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api and not javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api"

Comment: which error? `spring-security-config v. 5.7.3` depends on `spring-security-web v. 5.7.3` which was compiled against `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api`, meanwhile `spring-boot-starter-web` brings `jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api` as a runtime dependency, you might even do not see any `javax.servlet` classes in your project but nothing will work.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov the error occurs once I add the spring-security-config dependency (I need it for `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`). So I think that I have to completely get rid of using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, and finish reading the article you provided, I hope it may help.

Comment: yeap, that is the root cause. Actually a lot of spring guides abruptly became obsolete as soon as spring team released spring-6/spring-boot-3 in November, and there are two options: either stick with spring-5.3/spring-boot-2.x or learn spring-6/spring-boot-3 using official documentation. https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution was simple. If you're migrating to Spring 6, you should get rid of using the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class and instead configure your security without it.

I've written a new configuration (which does the same operations as well as the config provided in the question), and now it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        UserDetails user = User
                            .withUsername("spring_user")
                            .password(encoder.encode("password123"))
                            .roles("USER")
                            .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

That's the minimal configuration required by Spring Security 6 to provide basic authentication, default password encoder (which is recommended to use) and in-memory user.